# `bash: scp: command not found` while I do have `scp` in `$PATH`

Tags: ubuntu, path, openssh, scp

Here is my screen output:

```
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ scp -i ~/--------- browser-uat.zip ubuntu@yabuat:
bash: scp: command not found
lost connection
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ ssh -i ~/--------- ubuntu@yabuat
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$ scp
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$ echo $PATH
/opt/sonar/runner/bin:/snap/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8
-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/bin
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$ sudo apt install openssh-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
openssh-client is already the newest version (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1).
o upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 108 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$ exit
logout
Connection to yabuat closed.
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$
```

<sup>See: [Annotated screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjorX.png)</sup>

As shown in the screen copy, the `scp` command failed with

> ```
> bash: scp: command not found
> lost connection
> ```

However after I `ssh` into the remote server and type `scp` I can see that command is available, and my `$PATH` environment is good.

When I tried to install `openssh-client`, as suggested in many places, I get `openssh-client is already the newest version`

Now I am stuck and don't know what's wrong with the `scp` command.

### Update

I have `openssh-client` installed locally, nothing wrong with the local environment:

```
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ scp
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ echo $PATH
/opt/play:/opt/idea/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/home/loug/bin_local:/home/loug/bin:/home/loug/.nvm/versi
ons/node/v7.7.4/bin:/usr/local/share/resin/bin:/home/loug/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/us
r/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$
```

<sup>See: [Annotated screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnrlk.png)</sup>

### Updates II

A screen copy shows that `scp` command is available on both ends:

```
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ echo 'show we have local scp installed'
show we have local scp installed
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ scp
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ echo 'show teh error in scp files to remote'
show the error in scp files to remote
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ scp -i ~/.keys/yab-ci.pem browser-uat.zip ubuntu@yabuat:
bash: spc: command not found
lost connection
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ echo 'ssh into remote and test scp on remote'
ssh into remote and test scp on remote
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ ssh -i ~/.keys/yab-ci.pem ubuntu@yabuat
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$ scp
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$ exit
logout
Connection to yabuat closed.
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ echo 'so we proved the scp command available on both end'

so we proved the scp command available on both end
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$
```

<sup>See: [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwpKP.png)</sup>

### Update III

As required by one of the answers, here is the result of the `which scp` commands on the remote server and local system:

```
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ ssh -i ~/.keys/yab-ci.pem ubuntu@yabuat
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$ which scp
/usr/bin/scp
ubuntu@ip-172.31.25.135:~$ exit
logout
Connection to yabuat closed.
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ ssh -T -i ~/.keys/yab-ci.pem ubuntu@yabuat
^Cloug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ which scp
/usr/bin/scp
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$
```

<sup>See: [Annotated screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGEcJ.png)</sup>

Updates IV for Martin

@Martin, here is the result following your instruction

```
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ ssh -T -i ~/.keys/yab-ci.pem ubuntu@yabuat
loug@loug-Satellite-P50-A:~/Downloads$ which scp
/usr/bin/scp
scp
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

<sup>See: [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWnrE.png)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

It's quite likely that you have your remote `PATH` set to point to `scp` only for interactive sessions.

The `scp` uses non-interactive session.

To verify try to login with `ssh -T -i ...` and then try to run `scp`.

You should get the same error.

---

A different set of startup scripts is (might be) sourced for interactive and non-interactive sessions. And/or different branches in the scripts are taken, based on absence/presence of `TERM` environment variable (or similar).

You probably need to fix your startup scripts to set the `PATH` correctly in either situation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you have *scp* on only one of your host machines but not the other.

From your screen shot, we can see that *scp* exists on the host machine "ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-135", but it does not exist on the host machine "luog@luog-satellite-P50-A" host.

SCP must exist on **BOTH** machines to work correctly.

Install it on the "luog@luog-satellite-P50-A" host machine using `sudo apt-get install openssh-client`. It should work fine after that.

Regards,
Mike

Comment: No it's not the right answer. Please see updates

Comment: @green Could you provide the result of the command `which scp` . This should tell us to which path exactly the scp binaries are installed to.

Comment: See **updates III**

Answer (score 0):

Look at Your `~/.bashrc` file on remote machine. You probably modify `PATH` in it:

```
export PATH="$PATH;~/bin/"
```

or something similar. Comment this line. Now `scp` should works fine.

**EDIT:**

This is bug in `scp` https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20527

If You find broken code in `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$SSH_TTY" ]
then
    # broken code
fi
```

Comment: It's not a bug of `scp`. It's misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with zsh:

`zsh:1: command not found: scp`

The reason for the problem in my case what that `$PATH` wasn't set in non-interactive sessions (which is the case for `scp`).

My solution was:

`ln -s zprofile /etc/zsh/zshenv`

Presumably the solution with `bash` will be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe silly but do you have a variable name PATH inside your script ?

It happen to me, I use a variable name PATH which overwrite the actual $PATH.
Change this variable name, and you should be OK.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Anyone can do a stooped every once in a while, so not too bad as a suggestion :-) Doesn't apply in this situation, tho'. If you read carefully the question, you'll see no scripting is involved. OP is simply using `scp` on the command line.